# Realtime kernel on webserver with MySQL

Tags: apache2, mysql, webserver, realtime

Enabling realtime kernel will it increase the performance on Apache and MySQL webserver?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. We do intensive and a lot of MySQL transactions which become CPU-bound task (if I'm right?).

Comment: I don't think so. Transactions are I/O to the device on which the actual database is stored. CPU-bound means long-running computations like e.g. any type of number crunching.
In case you have any real-world problems with your database,  you may want to look e.g. for slow queries. Having I/O issues with a database may have multiple problems like bad table design (resulting in too many queries), missing (or wrong) indexes (resulting in slower access), too slow drives (resulting in I/O limitations) or undersized hardware.
Plus the webserver itself also needs some time for the I/O time.

Answer (score 2):

Typically not. Answering HTTP requests and querying a database is typically an I/O bound task, not a CPU-bound task. So the limiting factors are things like network speed, I/O on devices etc. A realtime kernel is typically only necessary when you need to control something in real time (or close to real time), e.g. a machine, a robot etc. A realtime kernel doesn't necessarily make the overall performance better.